# DELETE TRIGGER in MySql throwing error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I get an error (1064) when attempting to run the following...  (MySql 5.5.9)

query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER clearChat AFTER INSERT ON chat
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE p.* FROM chat p LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.id FROM chat t ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 50) x ON x.id = p.id WHERE x.id IS NULL
END;
```

the error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 5
```

Any assistance would be great.

Last Edit:  Updated to show the 'FOR EACH ROW' and 'BEGIN'

Comment: I ended up having PHP do this at the start of the input rather than the trigger, as Chris Morgan found down below that TRIGGERs don't seem to work for my exact scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `FOR EACH ROW` before `DELETE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

**Edit:** There are more issues.  The correct syntax is below:

```
delimiter |

    CREATE TRIGGER clearChat AFTER INSERT ON chat
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE p.* FROM chat p LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.id FROM chat t ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 50) x ON x.id = p.id WHERE x.id IS NULL;
      END;
|

delimiter ;
```

**Edit 2:**

I don't think that query is allowed to be in a trigger at all based on this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9:

> A trigger can access both old and new
>   data in its own table. A trigger can
>   also affect other tables, but it is
>   not permitted to modify a table that
>   is already being used (for reading or
>   writing) by the statement that invoked
>   the function or trigger.

Since you aren't using `OLD` or `NEW`, I don't think you can modify `chat` since the trigger is triggered on inserts to `chat`.

Comment: That is an optional command as I recall. After adding it I get error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 4

Comment: @JClaspill It is not optional (as indicated in the link I posted).  Edited to include delimiter portion and added the semicolon after your delete statement.

Comment: I was able to add it, but it never seems to trigger. So you get the solved answer here in a bit, but curious as to if you notice anything I'm doing wrong for it to not trigger(or if it does, it doesnt do anything when it triggers)?

Comment: @JClaspill Without seeing your data, it's hard to tell.  What does `SELECT p.* FROM chat p LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.id FROM chat t ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 50) x ON x.id = p.id WHERE x.id IS NULL;` return?

Comment: It gives me a resultset of rows outside the newest 50.

Comment: @Chris Good find. Looks like I can't do exactly what I was after. But you did fix my basic syntax. Thanks for all the help Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the following statement, it ALWAYS gave me a syntax error on even this simplified delete statement (originally was `DELETE FROM APP_CACHE_VIEW WHERE APP_UID = OLD.APP_UID;`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER APPLICATION_DELETE BEFORE DELETE ON APPLICATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM APP_CACHE_VIEW;
END
```

If I changed the SQL command to the following then it WORKED but I don't understand why:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER APPLICATION_DELETE BEFORE DELETE ON APPLICATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM APP_CACHE_VIEW;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```